# Video Compression using JavaCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, javacv

I'm using latest version of [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) to compress video and get mp4 file as per my requirement by using following piece of code.

```
    File inputFile = new File(UTILS.getAppDirPath(),actual_input_file.getName());
    File outputFile = new File(UTILS.getAppDirPath(),"comp_"+actual_file_name+".mp4");

    FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(inputFile); 

    grabber.start(); 

    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(outputFile, 
            grabber.getImageWidth(), grabber.getImageHeight(), 
            grabber.getAudioChannels()); 
    recorder.setFrameRate(grabber.getFrameRate()); 
    recorder.setSampleRate(grabber.getSampleRate()); 
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    if(grabber.getVideoBitrate()>bitrate)
    {
        recorder.setVideoBitrate(bitrate);
    }
    else
    {
        recorder.setVideoBitrate(grabber.getVideoBitrate());
    }
    recorder.start(); 
    int count = 0;
    Frame frame; 
    while ((frame = grabber.grabFrame()) != null) { 
        recorder.record(frame); 
        count++;
    } 
    recorder.stop(); 
    grabber.stop();
```

And these are the libraries which I have placed in `libs` directory of application,

```
/libs
/libs/armeabi
/libs/armeabi/libavcodec.so
libs/armeabi/libavdevice.so
libs/armeabi/libavfilter.so
libs/armeabi/libavformat.so
libs/armeabi/libavutil.so
libs/armeabi/libjniavcodec.so
libs/armeabi/libjniavdevice.so
libs/armeabi/libjniavfilter.so
libs/armeabi/libjniavformat.so
libs/armeabi/libjniavutil.so
libs/armeabi/libjnicvkernels.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_calib3d.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_contrib.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_core.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_features2d.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_flann.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_highgui.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_imgproc.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_legacy.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_ml.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_nonfree.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_objdetect.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_photo.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_stitching.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_superres.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_video.so
libs/armeabi/libjniopencv_videostab.so
libs/armeabi/libjnipostproc.so
libs/armeabi/libjniswresample.so
libs/armeabi/libjniswscale.so
libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so
libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so
libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so
libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so
libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_calib3d.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_contrib.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_core.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_features2d.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_flann.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_gpu.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_highgui.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_imgproc.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_legacy.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_ml.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_nonfree.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_objdetect.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_photo.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_stitching.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_superres.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_video.so
libs/armeabi/libopencv_videostab.so
libs/armeabi/libpostproc.so
libs/armeabi/libswresample.so
libs/armeabi/libswscale.so
libs/armeabi/libtbb.so
libs/android-support-v4.jar
libs/commons-net-3.3.jar
libs/ffmpeg.jar
libs/gson-2.2.4.jar
libs/javacpp.jar
libs/javacv.jar
libs/opencv.jar
```

**Issue:**

Everything is working fine when I test on Samsung Galaxy S4, Google Nexus 7, Samsung Galaxy Core.
It is failed with errors when I test on Motorola Razr,
Errors which I am facing:

- First error message:

  ```
  02-11 09:54:57.579: E/dalvikvm(22745): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.myapp.example.apk-1/libjniavdevice.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "av_input_audio_device_next" referenced by "libjniavdevice.so"...
  02-11 09:54:57.579: W/dalvikvm(22745): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/avdevice;
  ```
- Second error message:

  ```
  02-11 09:54:57.962: I/dalvikvm(22745): Could not find method java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSampleModel, referenced from method org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core$AbstractIplImage.createFrom`
  ```
- Third error message:

  ```
  02-11 09:54:58.300: W/System.err(22745): org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameRecorder$Exception: avcodec_open2() error -22: Could not open audio codec.`
  ```

**Note:**
As of now, I have included library files for armeabi and I do have the library files for x86 as well.
Can the processor of some specific devices (Motorola Razr) be the reason for such crash? i.e.: Motorola Razr has Krait processor.

Comment: FYI, this should be fixed in the latest version of 0.10...

Comment: @SamuelAudet: I've seen your similar comment on issue listed down on your github repository. But unfortunately, I'm still facing the issue in version 0.10

Comment: If those devices do not have an ARMv7 processor, it's not going to work unfortunately.

Comment: @SamuelAudet: it is having krait processor. How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: You can try to rebuild the native libraries as explained here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/#cppbuild-scripts

Comment: @SamuelAudet: I do have libraries for android-arm and android-x86 platform. And that script will generate the same again. right?

Comment: Not if you modify the files to support other processors than ARMv7

Comment: @SamuelAudet ok but for the device [Droid Razr](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=3827&c=motorola_droid_razr_maxx_hd_xt926_motorola_vanquish), CPU is [Krait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_Razr_HD) as [Snapdragon S4 MSM8960](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=cpu&id=a8960&c=qualcomm_snapdragon_s4_msm8960) which seems ARMv7.